# Maya and Android Applications - TCP to send Mel commands to Maya

Tags: java, android, sockets, android-asynctask, maya

Here is a fun one... I am trying to develop a Android app that will let users control a camera in Autodesk Maya (a 3d modeling application). You can tell Maya to listen for Mel commands (maya's scripting language) on a specific port. So, I wrote this app to send the commands and I get the following errors:

```
09-21 14:07:34.021  23651-23651/com.jvspad.mayaterm I/System.out﹕ Begin.... 09-21 14:07:34.071  23651-24337/com.jvspad.mayaterm E/TCP Client﹕ C: Connecting... 09-21 14:07:34.182  23651-24337/com.jvspad.mayaterm E/TCP﹕ C: Error
    java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /10.0.0.2 (port 1024): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:114)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
            at java.net.Socket.startupSocket(Socket.java:566)
            at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:225)
            at com.jvspad.mayaterm.DisplayMessageActivity$SendCommandTask.doInBackground(DisplayMessageActivity.java:71)
            at com.jvspad.mayaterm.DisplayMessageActivity$SendCommandTask.doInBackground(DisplayMessageActivity.java:62)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
     Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
            at libcore.io.Posix.connect(Native Method)
            at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:85)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
            at java.net.Socket.startupSocket(Socket.java:566)
            at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:225)
            at com.jvspad.mayaterm.DisplayMessageActivity$SendCommandTask.doInBackground(DisplayMessageActivity.java:71)
            at com.jvspad.mayaterm.DisplayMessageActivity$SendCommandTask.doInBackground(DisplayMessageActivity.java:62)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

So far I have ruled out the IP address and the port. I have also forwarded my port on the router when I first got this error. Could you guys help me rule out the possibility that it is something in my android application? Here is the relevant code for the Activity.

```
package com.jvspad.mayaterm;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;
//Using http://cs.lmu.edu/~ray/notes/javanetexamples/ as bases for connection...
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.io.*;

import android.util.Log;


public class DisplayMessageActivity extends Activity {

    private static final int SERVERPORT = 1024;
    private static final String SERVERIP = "10.0.0.2";

    //private OnMessageReceived mMessageListener = null;
    private boolean mRun = false;

    PrintWriter out;
    BufferedReader in;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        System.out.println("Begin....");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(TerminalWindow.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setTextSize(40);
        textView.setText(message);

        setContentView(textView);

        new SendCommandTask().execute("URL");

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private class SendCommandTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

            try {
                InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVERIP);
                Log.e("TCP Client", "C: Connecting...");

                //Make a socket to connect....
                Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);

                try {
                    out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);


                } catch (Exception e) {

                    Log.e("TCP", "S: Error", e);

                } finally {
                    //the socket must be closed. It is not possible to reconnect to this socket
                    // after it is closed, which means a new socket instance has to be created.
                    socket.close();
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {

                Log.e("TCP", "C: Error", e);

            }
            return "Comeplete";
        }

    }
}
```

Here is my Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.jvspad.mayaterm" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".TerminalWindow"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".DisplayMessageActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
            android:parentActivityName=".TerminalWindow" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.jvspad.mayaterm.TerminalWindow" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Thank you for the suggested edit. Ranjith. Do you see anything that looks off?

Answer (score 0):

You must open maya port first before sending commands to maya.

```
#force to close if its opened
cmds.commandPort(name=":9898", close=True)
#open new and change sourcetype to python if you sending python commands
cmds.commandPort(name=":9898", sourceType="mel")
```

I just realized that its old question :) .. anyways :)